# Mongodb querying nested objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pug, express

My Object is like,

```
{
   "Team-A": {
        "captain": "A",
        "homeGround": "some ground",
        "winLoss": "12-4-0"
    },
    "Team-B": {
        "captain": "B",
        "homeGround": "some ground 2",
        "winLoss": "4-4-4"
    }
}
```

I need to display this information as,

```
<h1>Team-A</h1>
<h2>some ground</h2>
<h3>12-4-0</h3>

<h1>Team-B</h1>
<h2>some ground2</h2>
<h3>4-4-4</h3>
```

**Nodejs:**

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/MY_DB_TEST", function(err, db) {
      if(!err) {
        console.log("We are connected");        

        var collection =  db.collection('football_teams');      
        var stream = collection.find().stream();

        stream.on("data", function(item){
            console.log(item);
            res.render('index', {obj: item });
        });     
      }
    });
```

**Jade:**

```
h1= obj.captain
h2= obj.homeGround
h3= obj.winLoss
```

My console output is:

```
{ _id: 51064fa1e0d5d118b4b29aa0,
  'Team-A': {
        'captain": 'A',
        'homeGround": 'some ground',
        'winLoss': '12-4-0'
    } }

title is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:176:8))
    at exports.compile (C:\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:181:12)
    at Object.exports.render (C:\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:216:14)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:243:13)
    at View.render (C:\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:75:8)
    at Function.app.render (C:\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:503:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (C:\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:721:7)
    at CursorStream.exports.index (C:\Users\HFR&D\Desktop\nodemongoexpress\routes\index.js:18:8)
    at CursorStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
    at CursorStream._onNextObject (C:\Users\HFR&D\Desktop\nodemongoexpress\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\cursorstream
```

I'm not understanding how I should loop through my object and get the values Team-A/Team-B and their respective details.

How do I achieve this using `nodejs` and `jade`.

**UPDATE:**

Say there are 20 teams, my collection will consists of 20 documents. What I want to do is, loop through my collection and display info in the 20 documents as described above.

- Is my db structure correct? Should I have a different document for each team?
- If yes, how do I get the title of the documents (team-A, team-B) dynamically while rendering in jade?

Comment: Can you show the whole index jade template?

Comment: @Guy That's all there is, there is a `extends layout` statement that extends my 'master page'. I'm very new to mongo/node/jade, so I don't know how to query the db to get the values `Team-A` and it's details. That's what I want to know

Comment: You need to rework your schema so that each team has its own document with a `name` field identifying the name of the team.

Answer (score 0):

You do get the Team-A collection as you see it in your console.log

```
{ _id: 51064fa1e0d5d118b4b29aa0,
  'Team-A': {
        'captain": 'A',
        'homeGround": 'some ground',
        'winLoss': '12-4-0'
    } }
```

The error you get is `title is not defined`, so I am guessing something else is breaking your code. (Perhaps the title variable for the layout is not set?)

After you fix that problem do like so

```
h1= obj['Team-A'].captain
h2= obj['Team-A'].homeGround
h3= obj['Team-A'].winLoss
```

That will give you the data.

Comment: Is it possible to get the 'Team-A' dynamically? since it's the name of my document. 

I've updated my question please have a look

Comment: You could check the object keys and match them to a regular expression, /Team-[A|B]/, if it finds it it'll return the one it found, then you can use that as obj[WhatIFoundFromRegex] but that's a bit a silly way of doing it, I'd listen to @JohnnyHK and change the database schema.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myobj = {
 "Team-A": {
   "captain": "A",
   "homeGround": "some ground",
   "winLoss": "12-4-0"
 },
 "Team-B": {
   "captain": "B",
   "homeGround": "some ground 2",
   "winLoss": "4-4-4"
 }
};

var key = Object.keys(obj)[0] // gives you the first key i.e. Team-A. its an array so every key is easily accessible.
var captain = myobj[key].captain // gives 'A'
var homeGround = myobj[key].homeGround // gives 'some ground'
var winloss = myobj[key].winloss //gives "12-4-0"
```